# How long is the Dominion of Winds in Guild Wars 2?

Tags: guild-wars-2

[image]

When I was browsing the map, I noticed that the Dominion of Winds only is partially shown on the map. Almost the whole eastern border of Caledon Forest is filled with the wall. In Kessex Hills, the wall is only shown a part at the southern border. But what about the rest of the wall? According to the race that lives inside the borders, the wall is fully complete and there is no interruption. I've drawn some possible locations of the wall. Does anyone know more about the Dominion?

EDIT: [image]

When I look at this map, I noticed that this map misses some islands. Is this map still accurate?

Comment: Lion's Arch has also part of the wall. There is WoodenPotatoes video where he looks at Wizard tower in 3d, where he looks around the wall from east side. -> https://youtu.be/Vb-vYZhbMes

Comment: This map is dated. The scar that runs from the Crystal Desert is far longer in-game.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this map](https://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/File:Tyria_map_(novel).jpg) from the novels, the wall forms a pretty tight perimeter around the two islands between Kryta and Southsun Cove. The closest you could get to the south wall would be Southsun Cove, and the closest to the east wall would be Claw Island, but the wall is pretty far from both of those places and I'm not sure if you can see the wall in-game.

Comment: No, you can't, I already tried to get as close as possible. But the weird thing is, on that novel map, some islands aren't shown, how's that declarable?